# SQL Auto Number rows with grouping

Tags: sql, numbers, row, auto

I am not sure if this can even be done, but what I am needing to do is create row numbers for specific columns and not just a simple row_number() as I need a specific pattern or sequence and am not sure how to handle this. Below is the desired result I am attempting in SQL.

```
COL_1   COL_2   DESIRED RESULT
AAA     AAA         0
AAA     BBB         1
AAA     BBB         1   
AAA     CCC         2
AAA     DDD         3
ABB     ABB         0
ABB     BBB         1
ABB     CCC         2
ABB     CCC         2
ABB     DDD         3
```

Comment: (1) Explain what the logic is.  "specific pattern or sequence" is rather vague.  (2) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (3) You presumably have an ordering to the data.  That ordering is not clear.  Is there a column with the ording?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret this as wanting to enumerate the values of `col_2` within `col_1`.

If so, you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by col_1 order by col_2) - 1 as ranking
from t;
```

This assumes that the ordering you want is based on the `col_2` column within each `col_1`.